# How to know from which email client the HTTP request was coming from?

Tags: php, email, http-headers, httprequest, newsletter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email client detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085332/email-client-detection)

I have a newsletter which will have a link to my websites pages. Now i want to know which email client (gmail, hotmail, outlook) the user opened the newsletter in and clicked the link to the website page.

The reason I want to know which email client, is because i want to customize the content in website pages based on the use of email client by users.

My Website pages will be coded in PHP

Comment: This is not possible with php and I doubt it can be done with javascript. if you click a link in an emailclient the link opens in your browser so the php can only detect browsertype with get_browser. peace

Comment: Voted for reopen, that's not really a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

Look at the User-Agent header ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']).

For users using webmails, the user-agent will be that of their browser; so you could look at the Referer header ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) too. (But notice that browsers don't send referer headers from https sites.)

Comment: thanks for response. So you basically saying we will only be able to figure out which browser they using but not the email client.