# How to get a receiver E-Mail program

Tags: php, html, css, email, tracking

I am currently creating an interactive email and I'd like to know what email program the receiver is using so I can return the specific CSS.

I tried it with

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mydomain.ch/getclient.php?">`

And then in the PHP I am looking for the browser with

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
```

Anyhow it does not give me the actual e-mail client but mostly Firefox or unknown.

It makes sense because it is an email client and not a browser.

Is there a way to find out what program the user is currently using?

Comment: So you want the recipient's computer to send you the private details of their inner workings whenever they open an email? Does the recipient know you're doing this?

Comment: I actually only want to know what email program they're using so that the right css can be loaded... Is this problematic because of privacy?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422754/how-to-know-from-which-email-client-the-http-request-was-coming-from which is already a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085332/email-client-detection . I suggest you read these posts.

Comment: Thanks, this one above helped me.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, especially since the gdpr updates.